# How to pass arguments from a javascript function to another function without calling it?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass variable after a calculation from a function to another function by passing it as an argument. But when I do this, the function gets called right away.

```js
let myarr = [2,4,6,8];
function checkaverage() {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i=0; i<myarr.length; ++i) {
     sum = sum + myarr[i];
     } 
 let averageis = sum/(myarr.length)
 averagealerter(averageis);
}
checkaverage();

function averagealerter(averageis) {
  alert("the average is "+ averageis)
};
```

Here, I passed the "averageis" variable as argument to function "averagealerter" for later use. But it gets called right away. What I want to accomplish is later call it by using "averagealerter()".

Comment: Return it from the function, store it in a variable, and pass that to your function later when you call it.

Comment: `setTimeout(() => averagealerter(averageis), later)` (where `later` is a time delay in milliseconds)

Comment: @Phil Alternatively, `setTimeout(averagealerter, later, averageis)`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon it's been so long since I've seen the mystical 3rd argument

Answer (score 1):

```
let myarr = [2,4,6,8];

function checkaverage() {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i=0; i<myarr.length; ++i) {
     sum = sum + myarr[i];
     } 
 let averageis = sum/(myarr.length)

 return averageis;
}

function averagealerter() {
  alert("the average is "+ checkaverage())
}

// call the averagealerter() function when required.
```

Comment: Why introduce a global variable dependency?

Comment: @Phil Pasted the wrong snippet of code from my fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You could `.bind` the `averageis` variable to the `averagealerter` and return that copy of the function.

Then, call that function to achieve the result:

```js
let myarr = [2,4,6,8];
function checkaverage() {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i=0; i<myarr.length; ++i) {
     sum = sum + myarr[i];
     } 
 let averageis = sum/(myarr.length)
 return averagealerter.bind(undefined,averageis);
}

function averagealerter(averageis) {
  alert("the average is "+ averageis)
};

let myaveragealerter = checkaverage();

myaveragealerter();
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is make the checkAverage function return a value so that the value can be used in other functions by just calling the function like below

```js
let myarr = [2,4,6,8];
function checkaverage() {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i=0; i<myarr.length; ++i) {
     sum = sum + myarr[i];
     } 
 let averageis = sum/(myarr.length)
 return averageis;
}

function averagealerter() {
  alert("the average is "+ checkaverage())
};
averagealerter()
```

Comment: You just copied my answer. How does that help anyone?